# How to post photos in foursquare using api in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, foursquare

I would like to post photos to Foursquare. I already have Foursquare integration and I'm able to access user's information, but  I don't know how to post images other than the profile picture. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

See foursquare's photos/add endpoint documentation: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add